# Sql how to have a repeating number until a certain number then starts over again

Tags: sql

I have a table where I need to select data from it and add/create a column that counts up to 5 then keeps repeating until there are no more rows selected.

I essentially need an output that looks like the below:

```
ColumnName
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5
... until all rows are returned.
```

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want `row_number()` and modulo arithmetic.  That would be something like this:

```
select 1 + ( (row_number() over (order by id) - 1) % 5)
from t;
```

`id` is any column in the table, particularly one that you would use for ordering the result set.

Note:  Modulo arithmetic varies by databases.  Some use `mod()` instead of `%`.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the database engine. In Oracle you could use:

```
SELECT CASE MOD(ROWNUM, 5)
         WHEN 0 THEN 5
         ELSE MOD(ROWNUM, 5)
       END AS ONE_TO_FIVE,
       t.*
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
```

### EDIT

Or you could use NVL and NULLIF:

```
SELECT NVL(NULLIF(MOD(ROWNUM, 5), 0), 5) AS ONE_TO_FIVE,
       t.*
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
```

Comment: Ah ha! That's an interesting way to do it!

Comment: Oh this is great for when I’m in Oracle, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are utilizing a database engine with ROW_NUMBER function you can utilize that, and then take the modulo 5 of that value:

```
SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() + 1) % 5 OVER(),
    other items
FROM ...
```

The above example is for SQL Server, as the DB engine is not specified ATM by OP.

Comment: Except this will count 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0 won't it?

Comment: Depends on the DB engine ;-)  Edited!